# move-item doesn't work in loop

Tags: loops, powershell, move

```
ls *.gif | Foreach { $newname = $_.Name -replace '\[','' -replace '\]',''
                     write-host $_.Name $newname
                     move-Item -Path $_.Name -Destination $newname; }
ls *.gif
```

So while trying to help someone rename files with [], I found out move-item doesn't work in a loop.  It seems to work just fine outside the loop.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Update: Based on the comment below, I want to clarify this: The special characters in the file names require you to use -LiteralPath parameter. -Path cannot handle those characters. Outside a loop, -Path works since you are escapting the special characters using `. This isn't possible when walking through a collection.

In a loop, you need to use -LiteralPath parameter instead of -Path.

```
-LiteralPath <string[]>
    Specifies the path to the current location of the items. Unlike Path, the value of
    LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. **No characters are interpreted as 
    wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation 
    marks.** Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to interpret any 
    characters as escape sequences.
```

SO, this will be:

```
GCI -Recurse *.txt | % { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination "SomenewName" }
```

Comment: While your solution is correct, it's not because you need to use -LiteralPath in a loop. It's because the original filename included '[' and ']' characters which are used in wildcard expansion.

Comment: Yes, that was my answer too. We have had a twitter discussion on this. This question is actually a result of that :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the pipeline binding feature of PowerShell, you can make this much simpler and eliminate the need for the explicit `Foreach-Object` e.g.:

```
ls *.gif | Move-Item -Destination {$_ -replace '\[|\]',''} -WhatIf
```

This works because the `LiteralPath` parameter is set up to bind `ByPropertyName`.  However you may wonder, where does it get a property by the name of "LiteralPath" from on the output of `Get-ChildItem` (alias ls).  Well it doesn't find that property name, however the `LiteralPath` parameter has an alias of `PSPath` defined which does exist on each object output by `Get-ChildItem`.  That's how it binds to the `LiteralPath` paramter.  The other speed tip here is that because the `Destination` parameter is also pipeline bound (ByPropertyName), you can use a `scriptblock` to provide the value.  And inside that scriptblock you have access to the pipeline object.

Inside the scriptblock, this uses the `-replace` operator to come up with the new name based on the original full name.  While I could have used `$_.FullName` or even `$_.Name` in this case (assuming you want to essentially rename the files within the same dir), I use just `$_`.  Since `-replace` is a string operator, it will coerce `$_` to a string before using it.  You can see what this would be by executing:

```
ls *.gif | Foreach {"$_"}
```

Which is the full path in this case but you have to be careful because you don't always get the full path e.g.:

```
ls | Foreach {"$_"}
```

displays just the filename.  In your examples (rename to same dir) this doesn't matter but in other cases it does. It is probably a good practice just to be explicit and use `$_.Name` or `$_.FullName` in a script but when hacking this stuff out at the console, I tend to use just `$_`. The saying: *it's a sharp stick, don't poke your eye out* applies here.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the "official" informations about the role of "`[`" in Path strings on [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx).

Or look in google for : Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week : "Taking Things (Like File Paths) Literally".

The only tip wich was not clear for me is that `Rename-Item` does not support `LiteralPath`, and that we can use `Move-Item` to rename files or directories.

JP

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (atleast in my situation.

```
Move-Item -literalpath $_.FullName -Destination ( ( ( (Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath $_.BaseName) -replace "\[","`[") -replace "\]","`]") )
```

Had hundreds of movies and it associated subtitles stored without folders. Decided to put each of the movies and subtitles in their own folders

### Full Code

```
Get-ChildItem -File | % 
{
    if(Test-Path -LiteralPath ( Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath $_.BaseName ))
    {
         Move-Item -literalpath $_.FullName -Destination ( ( ( (Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath $_.BaseName) -replace "\[","`[") -replace "\]","`]") ) 
    }
    else
    {
        New-Item ( Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath $_.BaseName ) -ItemType Directory 
        Move-Item $_ -Destination ( Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath $_.BaseName )
    }

}
```